# Garden simulator

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, functional-programming

I tried to write the program so that it runs without error but I want to improve the program so that it follows the Single Responsibility Principle.  What changes can I make to improve this program? I am a beginner in programming and not good at pseudocode or commenting so if there is anything I can do to also improve there.

```
 """
Pseudocode:
def main():
    set plants list
    day = 0
    food = 0
    display welcome()
    display plants()
    report_day()
    display_menu()
    get choice.lower()
    while choice != quit:
        if wait:

main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed the Python part of your program, since it makes your question off-topic. If the Python code works, you can put it back. If it doesn't work, the question wasn't ready for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

### Pseudocode

First, your block-quoted pseudo-code is too much like code, and not enough pseudo. The purpose of pseudo-code is understanding. If it doesn't help you to understand, or if it doesn't help someone else (like a professor) to understand, then you're doing it wrong. In general, I'd suggest writing your pseudo-code in successive waves of refinement. Something like this:

```
while not done:
    get user choice()
    if choice is 'wait':
        get rainfall()
        if rainfall amount < threshold:
            kill one plant()
        produce food from plants remaining()
    if choice is 'add plant':
        add new plant()
    if choice is 'display plants':
        display plants()
    if choice is 'quit':
        quit()
  
    print daily report()
```

That's probably enough to get yourself started writing code, and it might be enough to make a teacher happy. The details should be in the code itself, unless you are forced to change your logic.

### Naming

You need to read and apply the [Python style guide.](https://www.pep8.org)

In particular: documentation for functions goes in the function's docstring. Constants should be ALL_CAPS.

### Functions

You have some good functions. But I submit to you that each time you have a comment in your code, that's probably a good place for a function. Sometimes, you can combine several comments into a single function, but in general, if you're explaining what happens, you can explain better using a function and its accompanying docstring:

```
 if rainfall < high_threshold:                                     
     plant_die = random.choice(plants)  # pick random a plant for too little rain
     print(f"Sadly, your {plant_die} plant has died")              
     plants.remove(plant_die)  # remove plant from list
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
if rainfall < high_threshold:
    one_plant_dies(plants)
```

### Wrapping

Your text output functions are relying on the `print()` statement to emit each line. This means that wrapping of text is occurring at the line level.

In many cases, you would do better to use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)  module to perform wrapping for you, and put entire paragraphs in *"""triple quotes."""*

### Results

You have written all your functions as procedures -- subroutines that do not return a value. If you haven't encountered the `return` statement, I encourage you to read about it. You will find it very hard to use the SRP if you cannot return values.

Much of your code looks like:

```
print some information
get some input
```

That sort of thing is a good candidate for encapsulation in a function that returns *well validated* result. Thus, your code might be something like:

```
def get_user_preference(params):
    while True:
        print some information
        get some input
        if input is valid:
            return result(input)
```

### main()

There's a standard way to handle calling the main entry point of your program or module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The purpose and value of this is that it will call `main()` when you just run `python mycode.py` but it will *not* call anything if you `import mycode`. This is valuable if you are writing a program that is also a library, or if you are using a unit test driver that will import your code into its test engine.

Comment: thank you so much. I was able to fix my code and create the 3 functions for wait option. I still don't understand how I can come up with psuedo code prior to programming, but I will be working on that.